# Why I can't declare and run method in main method of Java class

Tags: java

Probably I missed something during checking Java core, but please help me to understand why I cannot use method declared in java main method which is commented

```
class R {
        public int cal(int a, int b) {
            return a + b;
        }

    public int cal3(int a, int b) {
        return a * b;
    }
}

public class Rect {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        /*public static int cal2 ( int a, int b){
            return a + b;
        }

        int ab2 = cal2(2,2);
        System.out.println(ab2);*/
        R r = new R();
        int ab = r.cal(2, 2);
        System.out.println(ab);

        int ab3 =r.cal3(2,3);
        System.out.println(ab3);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have methods inside of methods, plain and simple. It's not Java.

Comment: To call an instance method, you need an instance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a method inside another method.

```
public static int cal2 ( int a, int b){
        return a + b;
}

public static void main(String arg[]) {

    int ab2 = cal2(2);
    System.out.println(ab2);
    R r = new R();
    int ab = r.cal(2, 2);
    System.out.println(ab);

    int ab3 =r.cal3(2,3);
    System.out.println(ab3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, it is true that you cannot have a typical method defined inside another. But, for clarity, there is an equivalent (Java8 - *if that still needs to be stated these days*) using the [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) interface. For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> func = (a, b) -> a + b;
    System.out.println(func.apply(3, 4));
}
```

Comment: Meh, just syntactic sugar for an anonymous class, which has always been possible (for a useful value of "always").